# How to create MPEG-DASH content using java?

Tags: mpeg-dash

I am trying to create MPEG-DASH content. I found code to combine .m4s files in [mp4parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser). 
Please someone guide me to create such .m4s files and .mpd file.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution would be to use a third party service, like [Bitmovin](http://www.bitmovin.com), which offers an API and provides running [Java examples](https://developer.bitcodin.com/doc/api-clients/java), which you can easily integrate in your application.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. In 'bitmovin', we have to provide access to video to them. I am looking to create dash content in our side itself by adding a jar and convert. Please advice me.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a Java based utility that you can run on your own infrastructure or own cloud to create DASH files.

If so then the following fits the bill (I have not used it personally so can't comment on how easy/hard/good etc it is):

- https://github.com/castlabs/dashencrypt